# Divs resize and overlay jquery

Tags: jquery, resize, height, direction

i created a container with 4 divs. I need that on hover the div change is size and overlay the other divs.

Here a demo http://jsbin.com/ecuzof/113/edit

The problem: i want the bottom divs to grow from bottom to top instead from top to bottom like now.

Is it possible?
Thanks
G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Working Example](http://jsbin.com/ecuzof/119/edit)

You can set the `bottom` to `0` and the div's will then animate from the bottom, up. Also, notice that I have created two events - one for the top divs and one for the bottom set.

```
$(".riga .hoverific").hover(function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({
    width: "70%",
    height: "70%",
    backgroundColor: "lightBlue"
  }).css({'z-index':'3'});
}, function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({
    width: "50%",
    height: "50%",
    backgroundColor: "silver"
  }).css({'z-index':'1'});
});


$(".riga2 .hoverific").hover(function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({
    width: "70%",
    height: "70%",
    bottom: "0%",
    backgroundColor: "lightBlue"
  }).css({'z-index':'3'});
}, function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({
    width: "50%",
    height: "50%",
    backgroundColor: "silver"
  }).css({'z-index':'1'});
});
```

Comment: Thanks, works great! I added the bottom:0 in css, this way i have one event.

Comment: @user2316417 Excellent thinking